# Test for differences between (among) related, but not matched, samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, modeling

When two samples are related, or dependent, but the observations are not matched, are there any tests that will determine if the samples (means or otherwise) are different? I've searched extensively and have only found tests for matched samples, which is not what I need.

Comment: Two-way comparisons with paired samples are not restricted to matching. Siblings, twins, pre/post measurement, or responses to a question asked to both wife and husband might all be tested using, e.g., a t-test for paired samples. Could you clarify what your situation actually look like?

Comment: Example -- a sample is partitioned into two groups using a clustering algorithm. Those groups are then dependent. However, different subjects reside in each group and are not matched in any way. So, a paired t-test can't be used since no pairing is possible. However, the dependence between the two groups precludes using methods that require sample independence.

Comment: This probably shouldn't be tagged with 'paired-data'

Comment: @ndoogan I added it, but it's possible I misunderstood the situation. I will remove it. The OP should clarify the nature of the dependence.

Comment: Some related posts with interesting answers: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25941/t-test-for-partially-paired-and-partially-unpaired-data?noredirect=1&lq=1  and    https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/370953/analysing-pre-and-post-intervention-study-with-anonymous-responses