# Analyzing Pre- and Post-Survey Ordinal Data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likert, pre-post-comparison

I asked 293 participants to complete a pre and post-survey after a campaign. Two hundred ninety-three people responded to the pre-survey, and 254 responded to the post-survey. The responses are ordinal, "Extremely Familiar," "Very Familiar," "Moderately Familiar," "Slightly Familiar," and "Not Familiar at all."

I do not have access to individual responses as in person A response pre and post survey. I have counts such as 26 people picked extremely familiar in the pre-survey, and 53 picked it in the post-survey.

I am not sure how to analyze this data. Wilcoxon rank sum test I believe does not work because of the scales. I believe pairing does not work either. I would appreciate some help and guidance. Thank you!

Comment: Please explain the objective of the analyses.

Comment: Objective of the analysis is to test whether the intervention was successful. So we gave out a pre-survey did the intervention and handed out a post survey. Based on the post that is above do you think Cochran-Armitage test, Mann-Whitney test, or Kendall correlation is appropriate?

Comment: @utobi Reading the answers to the question you suggest as a duplicate, none seem to answer this one. Due to the details of the question, the first answer assumes we're dealing with a binary variable (not an ordinal one), and the second answer suggests to look at other threads. I think this other question may be a better candidate as a duplicate: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/370953/analysing-pre-and-post-intervention-study-with-anonymous-responses/