# Paired test or two-sample t-test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, paired-data

I am looking at whether there is a difference in the extent of `emotional tone` in student essays on two exams - one at `T1` and another at `T2`. Some of the students who took the exam at `T1` also took exam at `T2`. But there are students unique to each exam as well.

In order to examine the hypothesis that the mean `emotional tone` in essays at `T2` is greater than mean emotional tone at `T1`, should I be doing a `paired t-test` or `two-sample t-test`?

Or do you suggest that I separate students who took both exams and do a `paired t-test` on this sample and a two-sample t-test for test takers who only took the exam at T1 or T2?

Comment: Another Q on combined paired/unpaired data:   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25941/t-test-for-partially-paired-and-partially-unpaired-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plan seems OK. But you have to understand that the paired test for subjects who took both tests will be more likely to show a difference in emotional tone, if such a difference exists. (The two-sample test for two groups of independently selected subjects will have lower power.) The following example, with data suitably simulated in R, illustrate.

**Paired scores.** Suppose we have 50 subjects who took both tests.
They average around 100 on the first test, and there
is an average increase of several points in 'emotional tone' for each student. Because data are paired, we
are able to look mainly at the increase in emotional tone
without being distracted by the variability of test
scores due to differences among the 50 subjects.
Data might look somewhat like the data simulated in R below.

```
set.seed(2020)
x1 = rnorm(50, 100, 15)
et = rnorm(50, 4, 2)
x2 = .98*x1 + et + rnorm(50, 0, 1)
d = x2 - x1
summary(d);  sd(d)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-2.5581  0.4485  1.6450  2.0571  3.6346  8.5226 
[1] 2.442555  # SD of differences
```

Due to pairing, there is a positive correlation between
first and second test scores, illustrated in the plot below. The $40$ points above the line (through the origin with unit slope) represent students with
higher scores on the second exam, mainly due to the
emotional tone effect. A paired t test (that is, a one-sample test on differences in scores) shows a highly
significant effect (P-value very nearly $0)$.

```
cor(x1,x2)
[1] 0.9892561
plot(x1,x2,pch=20)
 abline(a=0,b=1,col="green")
```

[image]

```
t.test(d)

        One Sample t-test

data:  d
t = 5.9553, df = 49, p-value = 2.742e-07
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.362981 2.751314
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 2.057147
```

**Two independent samples of subjects.** Suppose that
50 randomly chosen subjects took the first test and
a different 50 randomly chosen subjects anticipated
to score several points higher in emotional tone took the second test.

We have two separate samples, and so inevitable variability in exam-taking ability
among subjects (modeled here by $\sigma = 15)$ will be apparent when we compare
scores on the first and second tests.

```
set.seed(420)
y1 = rnorm(50, 100, 15)
y2 = rnorm(50, 104, 15)
summary(y1); sd(y1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  55.77   90.20   98.28   98.50  108.76  128.80 
[1] 15.25291
summary(y2); sd(y2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  72.71   88.47  105.48  100.88  111.72  127.97 
[1] 14.01788
```

A stripchart plots the two samples; group means are shown as red `X`s. We are looking through a heavy 'fog' of variability, trying to discern the difference between $\mu_x = 100$ and $\mu_y = 104.$

```
y = c(y1, y2);  g = rep(1:2, each=50)
stripchart(y ~ g, ylim=c(0.5,2.5), pch="|")
```

[image]

Because we have two independent samples with no inherent order relationship between them, it is *not meaningful* to find a sample correlation. Various randomly selected 'pairings' might give correlations anywhere between $\pm 0.95,$ about half of them between $\pm 0.1.]$

A Welch 2-sample t test shows no significance.

```
t.test(y2,y1)

           Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  y2 and y1
t = 0.81253, df = 97.31, p-value = 0.4185
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -3.433908  8.194846
...
```

Comment: Many thanks! So do you suggest that I do both the tests and only conclude that emotional tone is significantly higher at T2 than T1 if BOTH the paired t-test and Welch test show significance?

Comment: I think you need to make it clear that you have two parts to your study. One with a relatively efficient paired model model. The other with a less efficient two-sample model. (If the two-sample test doesn't find an effect, you might mention the two-sample part only in a footnote of your report, explaining that it was somewhat of a long shot.)