# Robustness of Mann Whitney U Test for partially paired data

Tags: references, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, paired-data, robust

I'm curious if anyone is aware of a publication that addresses the following matter or could provide a mathematically or reasonable response to the following question:

In a pre-post study where participants are required to complete a questionnaire before and after an intervention, the data exhibits a paired nature. In such cases, it is appropriate to use a paired test, such as a paired t-test, to compare means.

However, it frequently occurs that participants only respond to one questionnaire (either the first or the second one, but not both). In an extreme scenario, no participant fills out both questionnaires. In such instances, we can assume independence between the two samples (as there are no multiple measurements). Consequently, a t-test for independent samples would be suitable.

Now, my question is this: If I have both participants who complete both questionnaires and participants who only complete one questionnaire, the data would be partially paired. Hence, I'm wondering if there is a threshold for selecting the appropriate test. How many pairs are required to use a paired t-test, or what is the maximum number of pairs for a t-test (independent samples) without a loss of power?

Comment: There's no threshold in the sense that none of these tests will fit if you want to use *all* data. You may use a mixed effects model in that case. However you should first think about possible reasons for missing values and to what extent those who only gave one answer deliver valuable information (could realistically be expected to fit the same model) for what you want to investigate. If not, you could analyse paired data only.

Comment: For related issues see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25941